# как сделать такую штуку ) CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3

скрин прикреплю. Подскажите как сделать такие границы чтобы в начало было ярко а в конце было не видно ) [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Comment: @aleksandr barakin  Хорошо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Картинкой..
Но если хотите извращений:

```css
.border {
  display: block;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(#000, transparent);
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask-size: 100% 75%;
  mask-image: linear-gradient(#000, transparent);
  mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  mask-size: 100% 75%;
}

.border::before,
.border::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.border::before {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
}

.border::after {
  width: 60%;
  height: 60%;
}

.border,
.border::before,
.border::after {
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="border"></div>
```

Comment: да также, но чтобы не было до конца а заканчивался

Comment: посмотрите как в картинке

Comment: @Адрей, дополнил

Comment: Спасибо, но когда добавляешь анимацию не корректно работает

Comment: вот код анимации

Comment: @keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
        transform: scale(0.8);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}